# Freeware Plugin to View HTML source generated by ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, plugins, view-source

Are there any freeware plugins that would help me view the HTML Source generated by ASP.NET?

Comment: It might be useful to rephrase this as a question...

Comment: If you are looking for the source code to ASP.NET web pages, you can't find that using any type or plugin. That code is executed on the server and is never returned back to the end user. The only way you'll ever see it is by breaking in and stealing the source files and opening them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) has many features. The [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) add-on for Firefox looks slick. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/firefox/easily-view-source-of-included-files-in-firefox/) is a walk through of using another add-on for FireFox.

If what your looking for is just to view the source, all browsers I am familiar with have that feature built in. [Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176222)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's Fiddler2 for IE

Or Firebug for FireFox

With these you see the real source generated by ASP.NET, not the mangled source as shown in a browsers 'view source' menu option

Answer (score 1):

You can use Internet Explorer's `View Source` button, under the '`Edit` menu. Firefox has something similar under the `View` menu.

Edit: If you're looking for the source code for the application, you won't be able to see that no matter what you do.  The server sends the client only what it wants the client to see.  For ASP.NET, this means you'll see ASP.NET generated control IDs and the like.  If you want to do this on your own without a web browser, try [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

Comment: But there is some hidden code that I am unable to view by viewsource. I am asking about someplugin that will let me view that code too

Comment: View HTML is a plugin that will give you the power to see the HTML search code for a webpage.

Comment: someplugin like this one as this one is not downloadable

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to look when that function is already built in to just about every single web browser out there. View Source is a standard feature.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) extension for Firefox will let you view 'generated' source (i.e. it includes changes made to the html by client side javascript etc..). Otherwise the standard 'view source' option available in any browser should suffice.